# Where is the Displacement node in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

I know how to achieve displacement in Blender, but lately I read Blender documentation and found this page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html.

My question: Is there anything like "Displacement" node? If so, where is it? - cause there is no example or tutorial of using it beside this documentation page. If there is no such thing why it is described on official documentation pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Displacement node is an upcoming feature - this is an example of the documentation being ahead of the official Blender release.

You’ll note that in the example image from the documentation the Material Output Displacement socket is a Vector type (it’s blue). At all ‘current’ releases of Blender the Displacement socket is a Scalar value (grey) and would act as displacement along the surface normal.

The Displacement node effectively allows you to generate the Vector displacement from a Scalar value to effectively mimic the displacement available at 2.79 of Blender. The new Vector displacement will be an exciting new feature (for me, at least) and should hopefully be a point where the experimental ‘true’ displacement becomes standard supported functionality (rather than ‘experimental’ and subject to change - as it has here!).

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the answer. But still, I think it is confusing for new comers and beginners.

Comment: @Jazzu I completely agree - it only makes sense if you know some background about the issues and functionality and the documentation could benefit from a sidenode or clarification that this relates to future functionality. Longer term it should sort itself out when the development catches up. It’s a rare situation where the documentation is ahead of the functionality - in most computing projects it’s normally the other way around and documentation is an afterthought!

Answer (score 4):

The `Displacement` node is added after 2.79b and is available in the experimental builds of Blender. Blender institute might release a 2.79c version of Blender in a soon future which will have the `Displacement` node as well. You can download the experimental builds [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

[image]