# Microdisplaement in Blender projecting only in one direction!

Tags: displacement

I am trying out Micro Displacement in Blender... but facing a strange issue - all the projection happening in one direction instead of polygon normal (please see the screenshot below)

I would really appreciate if anyone could point out what I am doing wrong :(

Here is the scene file if anyone needs:

[image: Micro Displacement stretch in one direction]
I will upload the blend file also in case anyone wants to have a look at it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are presumably using a version of Blender later than the official 2.79b release - at release 2.79b the Displacement socket of the Material Output node was a 'Scalar' value (meaning it represented a displacement along the surface normal at each point on the surface).

Note that the True Displacement feature was an Experimental feature at that release and subject to change at some point in the future.

If you were to download one of the 'nightly build' pre-release versions of Blender (eg, 2.79.5) or build from the latest source you would find additional features. One such feature affects the True Displacement - the Displacement socket of the Material Output node is no longer a Scalar value (it has changed from being grey coloured to being blue - to represent a Vector. This means that the Displacement now represents a Vector displacement (in Object space).

In order to mimic the previous behaviour (where the displacement would act along the surface normal) a new Displacement node has been introduced which will generate the vector from your scalar value to then pass to the Displacement socket.

See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/112162/29586

Comment: Thank you!
Didn't know about the displacement node.

Comment: Ok, now there is a new issue... when I use a high res greeble map / or just a noise texture its tearing open the edges! :(
https://i.imgur.com/6xt7jpC.png

Any solution?!

Comment: @saicode I can't replicate that result - perhaps there's something else causing the problem. Probably best to ask a new question showing the new setup with Displacement node (you can link it back to this question for some background).

Comment: I have posted a new question here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119530/greeble-cube-microdisplacement-how-to-prevent-edges-from-opening-up-and-becomi