# Greeble Cube Microdisplacement - how to prevent edges from opening up and becoming black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, experimental-features

Hi I am trying to create a greeble cube with hi res texture. But when I use microdisplacement it make the edges open up and create unsightly dark border - I have tried using bevel but then the edge is rounded and not crisp.

I can also use a pointiness texture to mask the edges but then there's border which does not look natural.

Does anyone have a solution to avoid such dark edges?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: displacement edge issue]
Here's the blend file in case anyone wants to examine it:
[image]

And here's the greeble texture:
https://i.imgur.com/G29bdCI.png

Comment: You should note that you are using different build than latest stable and what exactly, especially if you are using things added after certain version. And also provide image you have used for displacement (packed in blend file maybe).

Comment: Thanks cglav for your reply. 
I am using 2.79.6 (build:2018-09-06)
I have already added the greeble texture (displacement) at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your problem with Blender 2.79.6 as I don't have access to 2.79.6 and I can't load your file into 2.79.5 since I don't have a 'safe' environment that I can risk loading "foreign" blend files). I did try loading into 2.79b but without success (from your file I couldn’t get any displacement working - even after tweaking the material to remove the unsupported nodes).

I tried replicating your situation afresh in 2.79.5 using the default cube, adding Subsurface modifiers (one set to '6' and the other set to '3' - so 9 subdivisions) and with the following material :

[image: material]

This produced the following result :

[image: result]

I don't see any dark gaps and the edges all seem to displace correctly without splitting.

Can you try following these steps in a fresh file to see if you get the same results? - or identify anything that you have done different that may have resulted in the issue.

Comment: Hi Rich. Thanks for your reply. 
I followed your process on 2.79.5  and it's still there in a smaller extent.
Here is my result: https://i.imgur.com/M7QvRiF.jpg

Comment: @saicode Are you using Adaptive sub-division? If so, can you try again but using non-adaptive subdivision. The Adaptive subdivision is an experimental feature as as such may have issues and/or be subject to change. Certainly, at 2.79.5 the adaptive subdivision is only in the Experimental functionality set rather than 'standard' - and I can get some artifacts using it which aren't present when I use normal (non-adaptive) subdivision. I suspect this could be a problem with how the edges are being knitted together with different subdiv amounts.

Comment: I thought without 'adaptive' subdivision turned on (after turning on the experimental features in Cycles render tab) 
microdisplacement doesn't even work!

Comment: @saicode At release 2.79.5 of Blender the True Displacement feature is no longer 'Experimental' - it is now part of the 'standard' functionality. However, the *Adaptive* subdivision **is** still experimental - presumably because there are still known issues with it, perhaps this very issue. If you leave the Feature Set as 'Standard' you can therefore still use the microdisplacement - you just need to add enough subdivision levels to give it enough detail. For example, the sample image in my answer was created from the default cube with *9* subdiv levels (one modifier set to 6 and another at 3)