# Spherical Displacement direction

Tags: texturing, displacement

I am having problems getting displacement mapping to extrude in the correct direction on all sides of a sphere.  I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0r0UnaIK_Y

[image]

**UPDATED**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Vector/Displacement node now - instead of feeding a value directly into the Displacement socket. This is due to how the Displacement socket functionality has changed at the more recent versions of Blender (it’s a vector now, rather than a scalar.

See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119497/29586).

Comment: That seemed to work.  I also had to add a color invert if that makes any sense.  I will add a screenshot in the OP.  thx . 

If it makes a difference: running 2.79.6